# Как написать юнит-тесты для декодирования Bitmap?

Tags: юнит-тесты, kotlin, android-testing

В приложении есть следующий метод:

```
fun decodeImageResource(imageResId: Int): Bitmap? {
    try {
        val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply { inScaled = false }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(AppResources.appContext?.resources, imageResId, options)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.log()
    }
    return null
}
```

Думаю с какой "стороны зайти", чтобы его протестировать. Для тех, кому кажется этот метод странным и не ясна причина перехвата исключения в нём, сразу объясню, делается это для того чтобы выявить ошибку в логе, на случай, если `что-то пойдёт не так`.

Для более любопытных, загляните в сам метод `decodeResource`.

Comment: А чего тестировать то собрались?

Answer (score 2):

Первый ответ на 100% верный, но слишком общий, вот мой более прагматичный подход.

Подобного рода методы пишутся с целью решить задачу типа "дай мне что-то если сможешь". В данном случае вызывающая сторона никак не может повлиять на источник (ресурсы), потому что они (ресурсы) в Андроид статические и неизменные. Если там чего-то нет или что-то не так, уже ничего не изменишь и достаточно самого факта, что это нельзя получить и по сути неважно почему.

Поэтому, объем тестирования можно сузить до:

- отрицательный идентификатор ресурса
- нулевой идентификатор ресурса
- идентификатор существующего ресурса, valid bitmap
- идентификатор существующего ресурса, non bitmap, чтобы отработать ошибку декодирования

В самом методе ловить только задекларированные исключения (IllegalArgumentException), чтобы при остальных тесты "падали".

Comment: Вы за автора ответили на первый мой вопрос — а я надеялся, что он сам об этом подумает. Но всё равно согласен, плюс.

Comment: Автор что-то не очень активен :)

Comment: Может выжидает, пока тут появится полный набор тестов с комментариями. :)

Answer (score 1):

Про «с какой "стороны зайти", чтобы его протестировать»:

- Подумайте, какие могут быть варианты входных данных и каким должен быть результат выполнения метода в каждом из этих вариантов. Включите в том числе невалидные данные (некорректный id, нечитаемый (битый) битмап и тому подобное).
- Посмотрите, какие исключения может выбросить `decodeResource`. Каждое из них нужно либо обработать в этом методе, либо передать выше.

Про исключения:

- Если на уровне этого метода нельзя принять решение, что делать с ошибкой, то исключение нужно перехватывать где-то выше (т.е. в коде, который вызывает этот метод). Это как раз такой случай.

  Например, если не получилось декодировать и показать капчу, наверное нужно как-то получить новую. А если не прочиталась второстепенная картинка на веб-странице, то можно поставить заглушку и продолжать работу.
- Тесты должны проверять в том числе исключения. Это ещё одна причина не ловить исключение в методе.